# Cookies are not visible on front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, session-cookies

I attach and clear cookies with folllowing functions

```js
const attachCookies = async ({ res, token }) => {
    const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    res.cookie("token", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
        httpOnly: false,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
    })
}

const clearCookies = async ({ res }) => {
    res.clearCookie("token")
}
```

Such a config for attaching cookies was chosen so cookies don't fly away when i access not `/` but `/products`. Right logic?
But now, on front-end (React + axios) I don't see cookies in Developer Console (there's just no such a field as `token`), although cookies work and i can access `/products`, `/bookmarks`, etc.
How to set cookies visible on React front-end side and then how to clear them when logging user out?

tried different configs for cookies, can't find the right one

my cors config btw:

```js
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        // origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
        origin: true,
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    })
)
```

update:

1. Attaching cookies:

```js
const login = async (req, res) => {
    const token = createUserToken({ user: foundUser })
    attachCookies({ res, token })
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
        msg: "welcome back",
        user: foundUser,
    })
}
```

2. making request with 'custom' axios instance

```js
export const ozonAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1",
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

The request is in redux thunk, but I don't think it really matters

```js
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (credentials: dataType, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const resp = await ozonAPI("/auth/login", {
                method: "post",
                data: credentials,
            })
            return resp.data
        } catch (error: any) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: 1. Show how you use `attachCookies`. 2. Show how you send the request via axios